# What does “g’suffa” mean?

Tags: meaning, bavarian

> Oans, zwoa, drei, g’suffa!

The first three words in the above quote are Bavarian for “eins, zwei, drei”. Is *g’suffa* also Bavarian, and what does it mean?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zxHelCzB1QI

Comment: Und es heisst: "Oans, zwoa, gsuffa!". Was aber in keinster Weise unterstellt, dass Bayern nicht bis drei zählen könnten...

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It’s a Bavarian dialect expression and it means *gesoffen*. That’s the *Partizip Perfekt* of *saufen*: colloquial/vulg. for *trinken* (to drink).

Comment: +1 - Zudem ist es ein feststehender Trinkspruch.

Comment: +1 nur im Zusammenhang mit Bier anzuwenden.

Comment: Is that expression from "In München steht ein Hofbräuhaus?"

Comment: @Tom_Au The expression is older than the song.

Comment: A good translation would also have to include that "g'suffa!" is meant as a kind of prompt or even military-style order to take a gulp of beer.

Comment: @berd_k: Lässt sich auch mit Schnaps anwenden.

Comment: It’s worth noting that “saufen” is only vulgar or colloquial when applied to humans, as it is in this case. Otherwise, it’s the proper (non-vulgar) German verb for animals drinking. English doesn’t make this distinction for drinking, but it does with eating/feeding.

Answer (score 5):

*G’suffa* means *to guzzle* the drink down; it is not just drinking.

Comment: Und was heißt `to guzzle`? `Saufen, schlucken, verschlingen` - danke.

Answer (score 5):

My translation would be

> [Down the hatch](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Down+the+hatch).

Answer (score 3):

Well, I’m still learning a lot about the German language but I know that “eins, zwei, drei” is “1, 2, 3” and *g’suffa* is *chug*, *gulp* or *guzzle*. So this clearly is a drinking song! My uncle’s ex wife would sing this and drink German beer.

Answer (score 3):

*Saufen* is to *trinken* as *fressen* is to *essen*.  *Fressen* translates more "to wolf" down food or to eat as greedily as an animal. So too does *saufen/gesoffen* (g'suff') translate as "to slug" or "to chug" a drink in English or *chupar* whiskey in South American Spanish.

Answer (score 3):

This phrase comes from the song ["In München steht ein Hofbräuhaus.](http://ingeb.org/Lieder/inmunche.html) It uses the past of the verb "saufen" which refers to "serious" drinking; e.g. "tossing" one's beer.

Comment: I was quite skeptical about this short answer. Indeed the reference seems to give a wrong date and no explanation. But the fundamental info in this answer seems to be correct, surprisingly –– *if* you include 1,2,3 to gsuffa. See here for a short text you should also quote in your answer https://www.merkur.de/bayern/oans-zwoa-dreigsuffa-franke-erfunden-833739.html

Answer (score 1):

I was in Germany 50 years ago in the military and eins, zwei, dre soufa was what the Germans would toast to during a beer fest. The band would play, and then they would say, eins, zwei, dre soufa and everyone would gulp down their liter of beer.

Comment: Did they use Dre or Drei?