# Was heißt „O’zapft is“?

Tags: meaning, dialect, bavarian

Passend zum aktuellen Anlass möchte ich fragen, was denn nun

> O’zapft is!

eigentlich bedeutet und wo es herkommt. Prost!

Comment: Siehe auch: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/345/what-does-gsuffa-mean

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Nun, der Ausspruch erfolgt, wenn das erste Bierfass beim Oktoberfest vom Münchner Oberbürgermeister erfolgreich angezapft wurde, so dass das Bier raussprudelt bzw. abgezapft werden kann: Also stammt es aus dem Bairischen (bzw. Oberbairischen) und bedeutet so viel wie „Angezapft ist (es)“, was allerdings auf Hochdeutsch wiederum „Es ist angezapft“ heißen soll, und eröffnet damit offiziell das Oktoberfest!

Answer (score 9):

Es handelt sich hierbei um einen Ausdruck der bairischen Mundart *(Es) ist angezapft*, d. h. der Zapfhahn wurde ins Spundloch des Fasses geschlagen, man kann nun Bier zapfen.