# What does “Foama hoam!” mean?

Tags: dialect, austrian

I heard this expression from an Austrian commentator on a skiing video and couldn’t find anything on Google. It was used very excitedly!

It can be heard at 1:13 min in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uesDIWFetZo).

Comment: foama hoam ~ fahr'n mer heim ~ fahren wir heim ~ lass uns heim fahren ~ let's drive home

Answer (score 10):

The translation into standard German is:

> Fahren wir heim!

The *oa* diphthong is rather common for the Bavarian dialects (the dialects spoken in Austria (except Vorarlberg) and South Tyrol are Bavarian dialects) and often replace *ei* diphthongs in standard German. Note the similarity to [*oans, zwoa, drei, gsuffa*](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/345/15318).

The *oa* in *Foama*, however, is a different way of pronouncing a long *a*. Bavarian distinguishes between different *a* sounds (compare English *cat* and *bath)* and a long *bath*-type *a* can often be diphthongised to something like *oa* — especially more to the eastern part of the dialect space, where the Austrian cultural centre is. Western Bavarian would tend to pronounce the *r* stronger, as in *farma*.